# bool(false) and still value null

Tags: php, null, boolean

I am using this method to get a list of doctors :

```
public static function getFiltered($specialist = null, $standby = null, $payedThisYear = null, $payedLastYear = null) 
{
    $mysqli = connectdbMySQLI();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tblMember WHERE 1 = 1";

    if($specialist != null)
    {
        if ($specialist == true) 
            $query .= " AND specialist = true";
        else
            $query .= " AND specialist = false";
    }
}
```

The parameters (true/false) are set with different checkboxes. 
I checked the $specialist-value with a var_dump in Firebug. When $specialist is true, the query works fine. When it's false, it doesn't even enter the if-statement so appearentely it has suddenly become null.

Then I checked it with echo's in the if-statement with an else-statement and I got the same result...when $specialist = false, it goes straight to the 'else-statement'...

What can be wrong?

Comment: `var_dump(false == null, false === null);` http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PHP, the expression `(FALSE != NULL)` will always be `FALSE`, so code in your `if` block will never get executed.

This can be demonstrated using `var_dump()`. Consider the following expressions:

```
$specialist = false;
var_dump($specialist != null);
var_dump($specialist !== null);
```

The [output](https://eval.in/56534) will be:

```
bool(false) 
bool(true)
```

Use [strict comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) to resolve this issue:

```
if($specialist !== null)
{
    if ($specialist == true) 
        $query .= " AND specialist = true";
    else
        $query .= " AND specialist = false";
}
```

You could also use [`is_null()`](http://php.net/is_null) function.

Comment: In PHP null, null string, zero and false all have the same Boolean value, so you have to use the triple equal sign as Amal has shown. It checks the type and value both.

Answer (score 2):

Its simple:
When checkbox is unchecked, that field is not included in POST or GET requests when form is submitted, therefore it is null.

When getting that value from superglobal, you should check checkbox state using isset() to see if its marked or not. 
If you also need 'dont care' value, consider changing checkbox with 3 radio inputs. Checkbox only has 2 states.

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
if ($specialist) 
    $query .= " AND specialist = true";
else
    $query .= " AND specialist = false";
```

Or directly try like

```
$query .= " AND specialist = $specialist";
```

Comment: do NOT do this: `$query .= " AND specialist = $specialist";` You'll be asking for an injection attack.

Comment: @TecBrat See its the value of an checkbox.That's why I have given that ans...Thanks for that.Its also in my mind

Comment: An attacker can post anything he wants to your form, regardless of what input you are expecting.